# New worksheet for identified unique values only being made for text values

Tags: excel, vba

So I'm trying to get the following (repeating) unique values in Column E (5678, 8563, 5636, 1231) to be into new spreadsheets per value. The code below will do it just fine if I have something like "XXXX-XXXXX-" before the numbers it'll do as suggested but the moment I strip away the "XXXX-XXXXX-" it stops working, any ideas why?

```
Sub newworksheet()

' Creates worksheets per account number
Dim d As Range, Rng As Range, It As Range, k, nr As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
  Set Rng = .Range(Range("E2"), .Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
  With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    .CompareMode = vbBinaryCompare
    For Each d In Rng
      If Not .Exists(d.Value) Then
        .Add d.Value, d.Resize(, 12)
      Else
        Set .Item(d.Value) = Union(.Item(d.Value), d.Resize(, 12))
      End If
    Next
    For Each k In .keys
      For Each It In .Item(k).Areas
        If Not Evaluate("ISREF(" & k & "!E1)") Then Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = k
        nr = Worksheets(k).Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset().Row
        Sheets(k).Range("E" & nr).Resize(It.Rows.Count, 12) = It.Value
      Next It
      Sheets(k).Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Next k
  End With
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End Sub

Comment: What does the "stops working" look like exactly?

Comment: Subscript out of range

Comment: *On what line*?

Comment: @TimWilliams It'll identify the first unique value (ie 5678) and create the new worksheet but by the time it reaches the second unique value (these are all in a consecutive order) it'll give the error- I'm incredibly new to VBA so apologies for any beginner mistakes

Comment: If you hit "Debug" when it errors, which line is highlighted?

Comment: Get's stuck in For Each d In Rng
      If Not .Exists(d.Value) Then
        .Add d.Value, d.Resize(, 12)
      Else
        Set .Item(d.Value) = Union(.Item(d.Value), d.Resize(, 12))
      End If
    Next 

If I step out it immediately gives me "Run=time error'9': Subscript out of range"

Comment: *Which specific line* does it first stop on in that `If` block ?

Answer (score 0):

For this (and similar calls) -

```
Sheets(k).Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
```

If `k` is a number then that's asking for (eg) the 5678'th sheet.

```
Sheets(CStr(k)).Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
```

This version works for me:

```
Sub newworksheet()

    ' Creates worksheets per account number
    Dim d As Range, Rng As Range, It As Range, k, nr As Long, sht As Worksheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set Rng = .Range(.Range("E2"), .Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    End With

    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        .CompareMode = vbBinaryCompare

        For Each d In Rng
            If Not .Exists(d.Value) Then
              .Add d.Value, d.Resize(, 12)
            Else
              Set .Item(d.Value) = Union(.Item(d.Value), d.Resize(, 12))
            End If
        Next

        For Each k In .keys

            If Not Evaluate("ISREF(" & k & "!E1)") Then _
                 Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = k
            Set sht = Worksheets(CStr(k))

            For Each It In .Item(k).Areas
                nr = sht.Range("E" & sht.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
                sht.Range("E" & nr).Resize(It.Rows.Count, 12) = It.Value
            Next It
            sht.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
        Next k
    End With


Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```